# Move value in string to beginning of next string in list

Tags: python

I have searched and found how to move values to different positions within a string, but how do I move values between strings in a list?

However, instead of just adding to the number of values in the adjacent string in the list, I would like to move every ending characters from the remaining strings to the next except for the last string (where the number of words in the string would increase by 1).

**For example:**

```
lst = ['red black yellow', 'green blue', 'brown grey orange pink', 'white silver gold']
```

**Desired results:**

```
lst = ['red black', 'yellow green', 'blue brown grey orange', 'pink while silver gold']
```

Apologies for the lack of context, I'm still new to Python, so I'm not sure where to start on this.

Comment: (1) You split each string into words by using the `split()` method (2) you separate the last word from each string from the other words by using slice notation `[-1:]` and `[-1]` (3) you combine the last word from the previous string with the other words from the current string by joining them together with `' '.join(...)` (4) you add it to the final list by using the `append` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do this, which is pretty straightforward to follow.. definitely a cleaner way than all the ifs, but she works:

```
def shift(l):
    out = [] 
    for i, string in enumerate(l):
        current_strings = string.split('')
        if i > 0:
            prev_strings = l[i-1].split('')
        if i == len(lst) - 1:
            out.append(' '.join([prev_strings[-1], ' '.join(current_strings)]))
        elif i > 0:
            out.append(' '.join([prev_strings[-1], ' '.join(current_strings[:-1])]))
        else:
            out.append(' '.join(current_strings[:-1]))
    return out
        
    
lst = ['red black yellow', 'green blue', 'brown grey orange pink', 'white silver gold']
print(shift(lst))


['red black', 'yellow green', 'blue brown grey orange', 'pink white silver gold']
```

Comment: i think this can be done with simple `rfind()` instead of splitting and stitching it back. You can avoid all the if statements as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have a few answers but thought I will respond to this question.

You can use `rfind()` to find out the last ' ' in the string. Using that, you can move the last color from the current index to the next index.

Below is my code that does this using a simple for loop.

```
lst = ['red black yellow', 'green blue', 'brown grey orange pink', 'white silver gold']

print(lst) #printing the list before i make the change

for i in range(len(lst)-1): #iterate thru the list from 0 thru len -1

    r = lst[i].rfind(' ') #find the last color in the string

    lst[i+1] = lst[i][r+1:] + ' ' + lst[i+1] #update next string by adding last color to front of string

    lst[i] = lst[i][:r] #remove last color from current string as you moved it to next

print(lst)
```

Output of the above code is as follows:

```
['red black yellow', 'green blue', 'brown grey orange pink', 'white silver gold']
['red black', 'yellow green', 'blue brown grey orange', 'pink white silver gold']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go about doing this using python's `split()`, `join()` and `insert()` functions:

```
lst = ['red black yellow', 'green blue', 'brown grey orange pink', 'white silver gold']
to_append_str = ""

for i in range(len(lst)-1):
  element = lst[i]
  split_el = element.split()
  split_el.insert(0, to_append_str)
  to_append_str = split_el[-1]
  split_el.pop(-1)
  lst[i] = ' '.join(split_el).strip()

lst[-1] = to_append_str + " " + lst[-1]
print(lst) # Gives desired output
```

The flexibility you get with doing it like this is that even if the separator is not a space, but instead a comma for example, if you pass `","` as a parameter to `split()`, it would work!

Answer (score -2):

Create a seperate list of last words, set the first entry to an empty string. Then remove the last word in the main list and append the "last word" which was generated in the first list, here an example with list comprehension:

```
lst = ['red black yellow', 'green blue', 'brown grey orange pink', 'white silver gold']
lst_last_word = [""] + [x.split()[-1] for x in lst]
lst_out = [" ".join(x.split()[:-1] + [y]).rstrip() for (x,y) in zip(lst, lst_last_word)]
#out: ['red black', 'green yellow', 'brown grey orange blue', 'white silver pink']
```